Vue.js update html with data at specific index value
I'm just playing with a mix of vue.js and vanilla to try and create a blackjack game. I'm storing all the cards data in the vue data(), eg:
data(){
  return {
    cards: [
      {id: 1, cardName: 'Ace of Spades', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 2, cardName: 'Ace of Clubs', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 3, cardName: 'Ace of Heats', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
      {id: 4, cardName: 'Ace of Diamonds', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
    ]
  }
} 

I also have a randomiser built to pick a random number that can be used to grab the card at the same index value in the data. I have then been able to manually get card data at an index value pulled in to the HTML with something like this (for the first card in index value 0):
<div class="card">
    <div class="cPic" v-bind:style="{color: cards[0].color}">{{cards[0].cardPic}}</div>
    <div class="cName">{{cards[0].cardName}}</div>
</div>

However I want to update this HTML dynamically when clicking to draw a new card, with the data from a new random index value, ie:
{{cards[3].cardPic}} or {{cards[1].cardPic}}
and I tried simply updating the HTML with this (randomised number is stored in the variable randomCard):
document.querySelector('.card').innerHTML = `
    <div class="cPic" v-bind:style="{color: cards[` + randomCard + `].color}">{{cards[` + randomCard + `].cardPic}}</div>
    <div class="cName">{{cards[` + randomCard + `].cardName}}</div>
`;

However as I half expected updating the DOM like this doesn't work and although it pulls in the random number it doesn't pull in the actual data from the Vue data(). I've not been able to work out how to actually do it another way.
Any help on how can I update the card with the new data at the randomised index value? Thanks

hint: if you're using DOM methods in Vue, you're doing something wrong - Vue abstracts all that away for you

Don't manipulate DOM in Vue (manipulate VDOM if needed) since it's overridden by Vue anyway on updates.
Use a ref for the randomly selected card:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const cards = [
      {id: 1, cardName: 'Ace of Spades', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 2, cardName: 'Ace of Clubs', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 3, cardName: 'Ace of Heats', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
      {id: 4, cardName: 'Ace of Diamonds', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
    ]

const card = ref();

pickCard();

function pickCard(){
  card.value = cards[cards.length * Math.random() | 0];
}

</script>

<template>
<div class="card">
    <div class="cPic" v-bind:style="{color: card.color}">{{card.cardPic}}</div>
    <div class="cName">{{card.cardName}}</div>
</div>
<button @click="pickCard">Pick card</button>
</template>



const { ref, createApp } = Vue;

const cards = [
      {id: 1, cardName: 'Ace of Spades', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 2, cardName: 'Ace of Clubs', cardPic: '', color: 'black', value: 1},
      {id: 3, cardName: 'Ace of Heats', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
      {id: 4, cardName: 'Ace of Diamonds', cardPic: '', color: 'red', value: 1},
    ];

const App = {
  template: `
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cPic" v-bind:style="{color: card.color}">{{card.cardPic}}</div>
        <div class="cName">{{card.cardName}}</div>
    </div>
    <button @click="pickCard">Pick card</button>
  `,
  setup(props){
    const card = ref();

    pickCard();

    function pickCard(){
      card.value = cards[cards.length * Math.random() | 0];
    }
    return {
      card,
      pickCard
    }
  }
};

createApp(App).mount('#app');
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>




Thanks I can see this working really well in the playground, obviously I don't just want to copy your code and want to adapt it to work with my own. I'm only importing the library through import { createApp, ref } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'; Is there anything different I should be aware that would be different to work with the above?

@Chobbit i've created a runtime version in a snippet, just refactor to Options API (setup function), updated my answer

thank you so much for that extra effort with adding to the answer, it helps a lot and I've made it the answer :)
